# PHP - Naming class like a function

Tags: php, oop

I'd like to write a File-Class, but there is already a function in PHP which is called `file()`.

Am I allowed to name my class like the function?

```
<?
    class file{
        public function __construct(){
            /* DO_STH */
        }
    }

    $a = new file();
?>
```

It works without a problem (PHP 5.4). Do you know a reason for not doing it?

Comment: Keyword `new` helps the interpretet for call inference.

Comment: You may sometimes find `function Foo() { return new Foo; } Foo()->bar();`, although now that PHP supports `(new Foo())->bar()` it's not as useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions and classes exist in separate namespaces and their syntax is unambiguous. There's no problem for a class to use the same name as a function.